# cannot import name 'find_dir' from 'nltk.internals'

Tags: python, nltk, python-import, importerror

I started getting this error ever since I uninstalled nltk 3.0 and installed to the latest nltk-3.6.2

Just to ensure nothing wrong with my path, I also uninstalled pandas and re-installed again, no issues here.

Looking through the Traceback, I think the error is coming from this.

```
    C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\malt.py in <module>
     16 
     17 from nltk.data import ZipFilePathPointer
---> 18 from nltk.internals import find_dir, find_file, find_jars_within_path
     19 
     20 from nltk.parse.api import ParserI

ImportError: cannot import name 'find_dir' from 'nltk.internals' (C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py)
```

When I tried

```
from nltk.internals import find_file
```

There is no error, so I assume this works.

When I now try

```
from nltk.internals import find_dir
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'find_dir' from 'nltk.internals' (C:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py)
```

Anyway I could fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting!!

I feel really stupid for posting this qn. As a last resort, I tried restarting the kernel which did the trick.

**But I would be interested in learning what was causing this error?**

And is restarting the kernel **the solution** for such future issues?